# Best Foundation html nesting practice

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am learning to write responsive pages using Foundation and I wonder if it is better to use Foundation as a template (for some top divs) or to use foundation row/column size-number classes all the way?

What I mean is should I write my HTML like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-8 column">
            <div style="display: inline; width: 33%;"></div>
            <div style="display: inline; width: 33%;"></div>
            <div style="display: inline; width: 33%;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="small-4 column">
            <div style="display: inline; width: 33%;"></div>
            <div style="display: inline; width: 33%;"></div>
            <div style="display: inline; width: 33%;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Or like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-8 column">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-4 column></div>
                <div class="small-4 column></div>
                <div class="small-4 column></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="small-4 column">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-4 column></div>
                <div class="small-4 column></div>
                <div class="small-4 column></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This example is trivial just to show what I am asking for. My question is related to deeper nestings (like 5+ levels of row>column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second approach is definitely better because:

- **Flexibility**: size-number classes aren't only about floating layout, it's primary about responsivity. You are able to add some medium or large classes later and make different layout for different screens (this is not only about columns width but also about ability to change the position when a window is resized). Even if you don't suppose you need it now, who knows about future
- **Uniformity**: size-number classes (and the column one) aren't only about sizing and positioning. They are also used for the uniform look and feel because they are defined by a complex style sheet. If you need to redefine the style you redefine the style for the whole applicatin in the same time so you don't overlook any. This is about spaces, margin, padding and much more.
- **Clarity**: it is much more better to write CSS separatly in its files than styling in the code directly. Classes can be reused and CSS file is the first place where you looking for the style definitions (no matter if you are the new developer in the team or if you read your own code after a long time).
- **Compatibility**: Foundation developers know their code and it there is much more chance that new version of the Foundation will be compatible with the old Foundation version better than with your own code.